# Inspect HTTP REST service calls using HttpHandler in WPF application

Tags: wpf, rest, httphandler

I am having WPF application...which consumes REST service call.

Can I register HTTPHandler in my project to inspect the request/response of this REST service.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Would this help?](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2012/08/rest-services-in-net-with-httphandler.html)

Comment: did you type any link?

Comment: My response is the link.

Comment: :( thanks..let me try.

Comment: this is asp.net...my application is WPF (Desktop).

Comment: I realize that, take a look at the implementation of restHandler used in that example and see if it gives you any ideas.

Comment: But how do I register the HTTPHandler ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HttpClientHandler  for the same. below is link may be helpful.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler(v=vs.110).aspx